# Nodes: can't find material output or Diffuse BSDF

Tags: node-editor

I'm a new user of Blender and I wanted to try using bump maps.

I've watched a few tutorials online, looked here on Blender.SE and on the Blender guide, but I'm a bit stumped because I have different options than what I saw in the tutorials:

[This is what the tutorial show.](https://gyazo.com/70750f51414b15adc1a10ce4df2de258)[image]

I cannot find the material output or the Diffuse BSDF node anywhere. I'm wondering if I need to change my settings or if I am doing something wrong. I made sure to look at tutorials for the same version of Blender than what I use, in case it might be an issue.

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174/uploading-screen-shots-into-stack-exchange-questions-answers/

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos OP cannot upload with 1 rep at the time of writing.

Comment: Make sure you are using Cycles Render (drop down top middle). When you add a material it will not necessarily create nodes, you need to click "Use Nodes".

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you're not in Cycles Render mode (top horizontal menu bar), or maybe you are, but in the Node editor you are not in Shader mode (bottom horizontal menu bar)?

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was just writing up :-)

Comment: anoyingly not the case checked both im always in blender render and i made sure it was in shader mode too >.<